# Page is getting reload when dynamically adding iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` inside a page inside, which I want to load the `iframe` dynamically once user click on the link.

```
//div code
<div id="cs_feedback_pane" ><!-- iframe here --></div>


//link
<a href="#" id="cs_panel_link" onclick= "loadIframe();">Load iframe inside div</a>

//javascript code 
function loadIframe () {
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.frameBorder=0;
   iframe.setAttribute("src", 'myurl here ');
   document.getElementById('cs_feedback_pane').appendChild(iframe);
 }
```

`iframe` loads successfully after the click of anchor tag but the entire page gets refresh . does anyone have idea how to avoid page load ?

Comment: My codepen doesnt show any problems.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGjDr

Comment: How can you say, page is get refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your anchor with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="cs_panel_link" onclick= "loadIframe(); return false;">Load iframe inside div</a>
```

I changed the `href` and the `onclick`, to avoid jumping or re-freshing.

Comment: what do you think about putting the `return false;` to the function to keep it clear?

Comment: When the function in the onclick will return, the link will continue to act normal (anchor jumping or refresh on an error, or something else). To avoid this, let your onclick always to return false. -- Its just a workaround, if you need it, nothing else.

Comment: Ideally this should handled with `$('#cs_panel_link').on('click', loadIframe);`.

Comment: Yes, this is also an solution to go with jQuery binds but in the question i didn't read about jQuery so I gave an "old school" solution to avoid the problem. I totally agree with you to use jQuery with cool binding.

Comment: i tried your solutions but none wokred fr me ..can u write a sample cod ein fidlle or plunker ...would be frt help ...:(

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of loading it by `createElement` using

```
document.getElementById('cs_feedback_pane').innerHtml("<iframe src=""></iframe>");
```

As far as I know this shouldn't reload a page.